What do we call the length of the longest shortest path of a given node?
We know that the length of the longest shortest path of any two nodes in a graph is the diameter. But for a given node $i$, what do we call the length of the longest shortest path ending/starting at $i$?
Thanks so much!

graph eccentricity

Thanks very much!
